# Getting text from an EditText inside a ListView with a button returns wrong value

Tags: android, listview

I have a ListView with a Custom BaseAdapter. Each row of that ListView have an EditText and a Button. I want to get the EditText value when I click the button, but, after I clicked the button, the application will return the value of the other row instead. This is my getView method :

```
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        View v1 = convertView;
        if (v1 == null)
        {
            LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater)_c.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            v1 = vi.inflate(R.layout.annotation_item2, null);
            customHolder = new CustomHolder();
            customHolder.edtTotal = (EditText) v1.findViewById(R.id.edtTotal);
            customHolder.btnOk = (Button) v1.findViewById(R.id.btnOk);

            v1.setTag(customHolder);
        } else {
            customHolder = (CustomHolder) v1.getTag();
        }

        customHolder.btnOk.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Log.v("Value", customHolder.edtTotal.getText().toString());
           }
        });

        return v1;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this one it may help

```
  btnOk.setTag(customHolder.edtTotal);
     customHolder.btnOk.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                Log.v("Value",((EditText)v.getTag()).getText().toString());
           }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

You should try with `onItemClick`. This is some line of code:

```
@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
    EditText txtInfo = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.your_edittext_id);
    Button btnTest = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.your_button_id);
    final String text = txtInfo.getText().toString();
    //do sth to show your values.
    btnTest.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
             Log.v("Value", text);
        }
    });
}
```

Don't forget to implement  `AdapterView.OnItemClickListener` in your class. That above code run in your own class, not in the `adapter`

Comment: I think the op wants to click on a button, not the entire row of listview

Comment: I want to get the editText value through the button. I'm planning to add more buttons inside the listview with different functions later, so I don't think I can use onItemClick.

Comment: you add more button for each row or just for listview??

Comment: The buttons will be added for each row.

Comment: so just implement onItemClick like above code, than declare each button with its id.